# Rotating image so that it faces another image

Tags: java, rotation, affinetransform

I am creating a game and want the enemy to face the player as it follows the player. I have tried to use AffineTransform in this way:

```
at = new AffineTransform();
angle = Math.atan2(player.getY() - y,player.getX() - x) + (Math.PI / 2);
at.setToTranslation(x, y);
at.rotate(angle, width / 2, height / 2);
```

and then using `g2D.drawImage(image,at,this);` to draw the enemy on screen. The problem is that the enemy just faces a random location on the screen, it does rotate to face that point but it doesn't face the player as I want it to. I used the exact same code in the player class to make the player face the mouse cursor and then it worked just fine, so why doesn't it work for facing the player?

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct. While your question is slightly different (talking about the enemy facing the player), it's the same underlying problem as getting image X to face position Y.

Comment: @DuncanJones I specifically wrote that the code for facing the mouse cursor does not work for getting the player x and y and making the enemy image face the players position. Because that question answers how to get a image to face the mouse cursor it would not work for getting the enemy to face the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with your approach is that you do not take into consideration what angle the enemy is already facing (his image), he can be at the same (x,y) yet have any of the angles [0,360]. So your rotation seems random because while you rotate him with consideration to the player you do not rotate him with consideration to his own facing. You have to figure out what angle his image is facing, find out what angle the player is facing, then rotate him with regards to this.

I recommend adding a field to every enemy/player `Enum facing` (if few and limited angles) or `int facing` that holds the angle their image is facing.

Comment: Now my code looks like this:

Comment: `Vector2d position = new Vector2d(playerX, playerY);
            Vector2d zombie = new Vector2d(100,100);
            Vector2d facing = new Vector2d(0, -1);
            position.sub(zombie);
            position.normalize();
            facing.normalize();
            at = new AffineTransform();
            angle = position.angle(facing);
            angle = Math.atan2(playerY - y, playerX - x) + (Math.PI / 2);
            at.setToTranslation(x, y);
            at.rotate(angle, width / 2, height / 2);`

Comment: I seems like the zombie now faces the players spawn location at all time and not acctualy the player. I have that code in a Thread so it should update all the time.

Comment: Then the problem is playerX, playerY. They are not changed (try printing them out to console). You should have getters for them in the player-class, getPlayerX(), getPlayerY() so that you can maybe pass the Player object to the zombies and they will at all times know where the player is.

Comment: I tried adding                                                   `player = new Player();
playerX = player.getX();
playerY = player.getY();`                                                 to the thread but it still faces the players spawn

Comment: Did you print the playerX and playerY to see if they have changed when the player moves or changes x,y?

Comment: yes, it prints out the spawn coordiantes all the time, even when I move the player

Comment: If I print out the location of the player in the file that draws the player and the zombie onscreen it updates

Comment: Then the problem is that you are creating a NEW player with = new player in whatever class you are calculating the angles. You should not do that, you should send in the same player as the drawing uses into the class that calculates angles.

Comment: thanks, it worked when I created the method in the class that handles the drawings